# Visual Studio 2013 empty error list

Tags: visual-studio-2013, windows-8.1

My visual studio website project shows there are 2 errors however does not show them in the list. Any idea? Restarting visual studio and computer does not fix the issue.

I posted a screen shot here  https://i.stack.imgur.com/Giap0.png

Using Visual Studio 2013 Professional Version 12.0.30723.00 Update 3

Comment: What happens if you click the filter icon?

Comment: @markpsmith ah that did it. Thanks, didn't realize that would matter and that you could disable the filter completely, maybe since it is a website and not project this hides the errors.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed this by turning the error list filter off. Guess since this is a website and does not have a project it hides the errors when any of the filter options are selected.